# Browsers Not Receiving From Server

Tags: c, http, network-protocols

I'm writing a simple webserver and right now I'm just trying to set up a generic
response to see that it's working. Right now, it's only been working on Firefox and not
on Chrome or Opera. Below are some of the requests I've gotten and a generic response is at the end. Is there a line I'm missing in the response? Is there really a generic response to get the server up and running?

I see that the requests have "Connection: keep-alive", so I tried leaving the connection open for a few seconds, and that didn't seem to help. I tried sending the data separately from the response header and that didn't really help either.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.128
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15
Host: 192.168.1.128
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.128
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response here:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sun Apr 14 15:13:36 2013
Server: server_th
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 40
Connection: close

<html><body><h3>Hey!</h3></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response has no body, so you will see a blank page. Besides, it seems to be lacking the trailing CRLF, but I am not sure whether it is due to copy-paste.

Check the [HTTP specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html).

EDIT: in the updated response, body length is actually 39, although it is declared 40. could it be that the client is waiting for remaining payload?

Comment: I had forgotten to post the rest of the response, it's up there now

Comment: is body length deliberately smaller than Content-Length (39 instead of 40)?

Comment: thank you! the problem was the content length, and now it works perfectly. thanks!